# The foam around the object on a Ocean Modifier doesn’t look convincing and its glitchy

Tags: dynamic-paint, ocean-simulation

I want the scene to be a close up shot. Foam seems to be fine from a distance but when its close to the camera, it kinda looks fake.

First problem is the "foam around the object". I have used dynamic paint for that with box(object) being brush and ocean as canvas and used noise textures to obtain randomized foam.

It looks more like a 2d plate and seems to be glitchy and not convincing. And same goes with the foam on ocean modifier waves. How can I make it look believable? Been trying all ways to achieve it.

[image: Rendered image of foam]

Below is reference image
[image: reference_img for foam]

[image]

[Here is the video of how I want the foam to look like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nxzm3dPKuY1ZGU-JvIuc0P5tUW4kWa4T/view?usp=drive_link)

[This is the rendered video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CDX5mhrhGLBPFPbrrPAUXFR8Fk42kbQB/view?usp=drive_link)